# Escribir una cadena de caracteres y encriptarlo reemplazando cada caracter en 7 posiciones

Tags: java

Tenemos que reemplazar cada carácter en 7 posiciones más:
Entrada:
HOLA
Salida:
OVSH

Lo que pude descifrar es que ya existe una cadena predeterminada que es el abecedario, por lo cual la cadena que ingrese el usuario va ser reemplazada por la posición de la misma letra en cadena del abecedario sumándole 7 posiciones más. [image: Aquí el problema más especificado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te piden es el cifrado de César. Te recomiendo que le eches una leída a este artículo, no para que lo copies tal cual porque no sé qué lenguaje estes manejando (acá viene en Java) pero si para que estudies y analices su lógica, espero que te sirva.

http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2016/02/cifrado-cesar-java.html?m=1

Comment: Gracias bro!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de muchas formas. Como bien dice leonel es cifrado cesar, es decir que sumes un número determinado al numero que representa cada caracter. Yo lo haria pasando la letra a numero de ascii y luego sumandole 7 a cada letra hazlo en bucle hasta que llegue la t y entonces corresponde asignarle el valor de a asi hasta la z

Comment: Muchas gracias!!